# Django: Apply filter to a model, ignoring some filters depending on arguments values

Tags: django, conditional-statements, django-filter

what I need, is to apply a simple filter, but fields of the filter depend on the values of the arguments... so if some arguments doesn't meet the requirements, these must be ignored...
For example, given the model:"Telephone" and Arguments: color='black', size=55;   I'd need something like:

```
Telephones.objects.filter(outer_color=color if color='red' else IGNORE outer_color, screen_size=size if size > 0 else IGNORE screen_size)
```

With the following result:

```
Telephone.objects.filter(screen_size=size)
```

In this case, the field outer_color was ignored because it didn't meet the requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using kind of hack (I'm sure this is not the 'pythonic way....), using the 'eval()' function...so this was more or less like this (usig the above example):

> The following says: if color='red' then outer_color value is a string 'outer_color="red"', but if color is something else, then outer_color is a void string ''

```
color = 'outer_color="{0}", '.format(color) if color='red' else ''
```

> The following says: if size>0 then screen_size value is a string 'screen_size=55', but if size<=0, then screen_size is a void string ''

```
size = 'screen_size={0}, '.format(size) if size<=0 else ''
```

> Then, create the string statement:

```
my_str = 'Telephone.objects.filter({0}{1}.format(color, size)[:-2] + ')'
```

> And finally, evaluate the expression:

```
telephones = eval(my_str)
```

Hope this can help someone...